# Intalling python packages with pip versus installing from Linux repository

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, package

I am working with python3 on Debian Stable Linux. I see that I can install most packages from Debian repository as well as using `pip install packagename` command.

Is there any difference between these two approaches and should I prefer one over the other? Are the location of packages installed different in two methods? Thanks for your answers/comments.

Comment: If you have multiple virtual environments in python, using pip, you can install package in different environment.  But with apt-get, you cannot choose.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to install or uninstall modules with the Pip, or Pip3 command.